# How to nest a customScrollView inside a listView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to nest a list with sticky headers inside a `LisView` using the [flutter_sticky_header](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header) library.

Any help to achieve that is much appriciated.

The `SoldEntryPage()` is a Column widget containing some Containers

This is the PageView containing the ListView

```
PageView(
          
          controller: _pageController,
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            setState(() => selectedBarIndex= index);
          },
          children: <Widget>[
            
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
              
              // Container(color: Colors.purple, child: NewEntryPage(),),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 0.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: NewEntryPage()),
            ],),
            ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                SoldEntryPage(),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListExample()
                  )
                
              ],
            ),
           
            
          ],
        ),
```

this is the list with sticky_headers

```
import './common.dart';

class ListExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListExample({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppScaffold(
      title: 'List Example',
      slivers: [
        _StickyHeaderList(index: 0),
        _StickyHeaderList(index: 1),
        _StickyHeaderList(index: 2),
        _StickyHeaderList(index: 3),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _StickyHeaderList extends StatelessWidget {
  const _StickyHeaderList({
    Key key,
    this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverStickyHeader(
      header: Header(index: index),
      sliver: SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (context, i) => ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: Text('$index'),
            ),
            title: Text('List tile #$i'),
          ),
          childCount: 6,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the `AppScaffold`

```
class AppScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppScaffold({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.slivers,
    this.reverse = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final List<Widget> slivers;
  final bool reverse;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultStickyHeaderController(
      child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: slivers,
          reverse: reverse,
        ),
      // Scaffold(
      //   appBar: AppBar(
      //     title: Text(title),
      //   ),
      //   body: CustomScrollView(
      //     slivers: slivers,
      //     reverse: reverse,
      //   ),
      //   floatingActionButton: const _FloatingActionButton(),
      // ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting this error back in the stack

```
E/flutter ( 6715): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box with no size.
E/flutter ( 6715): The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderIndexedSemantics#149c7 NEEDS-PAINT:
E/flutter ( 6715):   needs compositing
E/flutter ( 6715):   creator: IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ← _SliverFillViewportRenderObjectWidget ← _SliverFractionalPadding ← SliverFillViewport ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a646f] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← ⋯
E/flutter ( 6715):   parentData: index=1; layoutOffset=320.0
E/flutter ( 6715):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=320.0, h=433.3)
E/flutter ( 6715):   semantic boundary
E/flutter ( 6715):   size: MISSING
E/flutter ( 6715):   index: 1
E/flutter ( 6715): Although this node is not marked as needing layout, its size is not set.
E/flutter ( 6715): A RenderBox object must have an explicit size before it can be hit-tested. Make sure that the RenderBox in question sets its size during layout.
E/flutter ( 6715): #0      RenderBox.hitTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2125:9)
E/flutter ( 6715): #1      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2140:6)
E/flutter ( 6715): #2      RenderSliverHelpers.hitTestBoxChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1679:22)
E/flutter ( 6715): #3      BoxHitTestResult.addWithRawTransform (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:808:31)
E/flutter ( 6715): #4      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:765:12)
E/flutter ( 6715): #5      RenderSliverHelpers.hitTestBoxChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1675:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #6      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:564:11)
E/flutter ( 6715): #7      RenderSliver.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1294:11)
E/flutter ( 6715): #8      SliverHitTestResult.addWithAxisOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:864:31)
E/flutter ( 6715): #9      RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:221:14)
E/flutter ( 6715): #10     RenderSliver.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1294:11)
E/flutter ( 6715): #11     RenderViewportBase.hitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:645:24)
E/flutter ( 6715): #12     BoxHitTestResult.addWithRawTransform (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:808:31)
E/flutter ( 6715): #13     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintTransform (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:736:12)
E/flutter ( 6715): #14     RenderViewportBase.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:641:33)
E/flutter ( 6715): #15     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2142:11)
E/flutter ( 6715): #16     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #17     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2142:11)
E/flutter ( 6715): #18     RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3121:31)
E/flutter ( 6715): #19     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #20     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2142:11)
E/flutter ( 6715): #21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #22     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:167:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #23     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #24     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2142:11)
E/flutter ( 6715): #25     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #26     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:167:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #28     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2142:11)
E/flutter ( 6715): #29     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #30     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2142:11)
E/flutter ( 6715): #31     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:19)
E/flutter ( 6715): #32     RenderCustomPaint.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:508:18)
E/flutter ( 6715): #33     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2142:11)
I/art     ( 6715): Enter while loop.
D/OpenGLRenderer( 6715): ~SurfaceViewPositionUpdater unlock <0x8f2860a0>
D/OpenGLRenderer( 6715): ~CanvasContext() 0x8f2ce000
Application finished.
```

Comment: Have you try add `shrinkWrap : true` in your list view, and also added scrollDirection could help if the both direction were different

Comment: tried that with no success @AldyYuan

Comment: Well, I think you can try to replace ListView with `SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate( [ //children ] ) )`

Comment: same output, I updated the question with the error i get back if it helps @AldyYuan

Comment: From the error I think you should wrap your ListExample() with Expanded Widget, and you can keep using ListView

Comment: did that ,still having the same exact error @AldyYuan

Comment: Welp I thought it will worked out, because the error said render box has no size. Are you wrapping ListView inside column or row? if it so try Wrap the ListView with expanded

Comment: the ListView() was inside a PageView actually, I am sharing the whole pageView widget take a look in the question @AldyYuan

Comment: I see the PageView has no size, wrap it inside expanded, it could solve the problem. If it still occurs well I guess I can't help furthermore, sorry.